# How retrofit call adapter can directly return Livedata?

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit

I am currently using retrofit with MVVM and I came to know that we can return livedata directly like

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("users/{id}")
fun getUser(
    @Path("id") id: Int
  ): LiveData<User>
```

I just want to know what benefit we get if we return live data object and how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Advantages of LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#the_advantages_of_using_livedata).

Comment: you have to use viewmodel for that

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman i am using mvvm from long time and using call adapter but my question is what if we directly return livedata from retrofit interface.